# Downward density of w-REA sets under arithmetic reducibility?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

Is the question of the downward density of the w-REA sets under $\leq_a$ still open?  If not can anyone point me to a proof?  That is do we know if for every $\omega$-REA set $X >_a 0_a$ there exists another $\omega$-REA $Y$ with $X >_a Y >_a 0$?

I presume it is still open and it's an interesting question IMO but before wasting any time on it I figured I'd ask a bit more widely to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Probably still open. James Barnes' dissertation (2018) addresses initial segments under the arithmetic reducibility, but is not specifically about $\omega$-CEA degrees.

*Barnes, James S.*, [**On the decidability of the $\Sigma_2$ theories of the arithmetic and hyperarithmetic degrees as uppersemilattices**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/jsl.2017.51), J. Symb. Log. 82, No. 4, 1496-1518 (2017). [ZBL1391.03031](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1391.03031).

Comment: I'm pretty surprised that anyone knows what is in my dissertation.

Comment: @James did you think about the $\omega$-CEA question at all?

Comment: I did not. The questions of initial segments (or, dually, density) were answered by you and Shore for the hyperdegrees and M. Simpson (not Steve) for the arithmetic degrees. I worked on the "other end" determining when we can extend embedding.